# PHPSpreadsheet issue with PHP v5.5

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

This isn't particularly a coding question.

I have a script running locally (PHP V5.6) and it's absolutely perfect.

However, I FTPd it to our dev server to run as a cron and it failed. Our server has php v5.5 running for dependancy issues. Is there any way I can user composer require to install phpspreadsheet on a machine running PHP 5.5?

Comment: I had to maintain the old php 5.6, which version is running `absolutely perfect` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPSpreadsheet was deliberately written for PHP >=5.6.0 because I was fed up with the way people had made death threats to me for even suggesting that the minimum version of PHP required to run its predecessor (PHPExcel) should be increased from PHP 5.2 to take advantage of newer features of the language to reduce the codebase and memory footprint, and make it more performant

PHPSpreadsheet uses features of PHP that are only available in PHP 5.6 or above, and will soon drop support for even that version when Security support ends for that version of PHP on 31 Dec 2018, and require a minimum of PHP 7.1.0

If you need to create spreadsheets using older unsupported versions of PHP, then you can't use PHPSpreadsheet, and can only use its predecessor PHPExcel

Comment: Is it difficult to convert the script I currently have to PHPExcel? Other than installing a new package, it looks like a lot of the syntax is very similar if not the same

Answer (score 0):

No, PhpSperadsheet requires v5.6 or above.

In the docs @ https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Software requirements

The following software is required to develop using PhpSpreadsheet:

```
**PHP version 5.6 or newer**
PHP extension php_zip enabled
PHP extension php_xml enabled
PHP extension php_gd2 enabled (if not compiled in)
```

Try upgrading PHP.